# Multiple Sencha CMD on Mac

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, sencha-command

How can we setup multiple Sencha cmds on Mac?

I am working with various versions of Sencha & I need to work with multiple Sencha cmd versions.

Right now I have to install/uninstall each time I need to switch to a different version.

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple versions of Sencha using the command line as follows:

```
$ SenchaCmd-6.x.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub -q -dir /home/user/SC-6.x
```

The output of the installation will now be on `/home/user/SenchaCmd-6.x.y.z`. Use syslink or custom aliases to switch between multiple versions.